# How to run an SBT task prefixed with a configuration in batch mode?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT interactive mode I can prefix tasks with configuration names (scoped commands):

```
$ sbt
> compile
> Compile / compile
> Test / compile
```

I can also run tasks in batch mode (non-interactive mode)

```
$ sbt compile
```

but running

```
$ sbt Test / compile
```

gives an error

```
[info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
[error] Not a valid command: Test (similar: set, last, exit)
[error] Not a valid project ID: Test
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Not a valid key: Test (similar: test, testOnly, dist)
[error] Test
[error]     ^
```

How do I run configuration-prefixed tasks in batch mode in SBT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run configuration-level tasks in batch mode try using `test:` prefix like so

```
sbt test:compile
sbt test:clean test:compile
```

or surrounded with quotes

```
sbt "Test / compile"
sbt ";Test / clean; Test / compile"
```

Also we could set configuration scope once and then all subsequent commands would be scoped to this configuration like so

```
sbt ";set configuration := Test; clean; compile"
```